Как сбилдить готовое приложение на React js?
Есть готовое приложение на React js со следующей структурой. Вопрос в том, как это сбилдить в обычные js и css файлы. Npm run build мало чем помогает, говорит о том, что нет файла package.json.
[

Нужен package.json, т.к. в нем вся инфа о проекте, зависимостях и так далее

К сожалению, Вам обязательно нужен package.json, иначе Вы не сможете собрать приложение. Есть вариант сделать все руками, для этого удаляем папку node_modules и запускаем проект, каждая зависимость будет выпадать в качестве ошибки и по очереди устанавливаем их с помощью npm
